# FirebaseUI database and auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to make an adapter that will show to listview real time database content.

I am using my own class and I want the line to show limited things from class.

I get FATAL EXCEPTION: main when I try to run.

---EDIT---

I noticed that what's happening is that the auth uid returns null while user is not null.

auth that returns null with adapter:

```
private void prepareRequests() {
    auth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OnStart.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                databaseRef = database.getReference("requests").child(user.getUid());
            }
        }
    });
    FirebaseListAdapter<Request> requestAdapter;
    try {
        requestAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Request>(
                this,
                Request.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                databaseRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Request model, int position) {
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.requestName)).setText(model.getRequestName());
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.handled)).setText(model.getHandled());
            }
        };

    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        Request request = new Request("Make new request here!", "false", "no one", "None", 0, 0, "No Message");
        databaseRef.child("Request").setValue(request);
        requestAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Request>(
                this,
                Request.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                databaseRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Request model, int position) {
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.requestName)).setText(model.getRequestName());
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.handled)).setText(model.getHandled());
            }
        };
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_req);
    listView.setAdapter(requestAdapter);
}
```

class:

```
public class Request {
    private String requestname;
    private String handled;
    private String type;
    private String handler;
    private String message;
    private double lat;
    private double longt;

    public Request() {
    }

    public Request(String requestname, String handled, String handler, String type, double lat, double longt, String message) {
        this.requestname = requestname;
        this.handled = handled;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.longt = longt;
        this.type = type;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getRequestName(){
        return requestname;
    }

    public void setRequestName(String requestname){
        this.requestname = requestname;
    }

    public double getLat () {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLongt() {
        return longt;
    }

    public void setLongt(double longt) {
        this.longt = longt;
    }

    public String getHandled() {
        return handled;
    }

    public void setHandled(String handled){
        this.handled = handled;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public void setType (String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }

    public void setHandler(String handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

request layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/requestName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/handled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat:

> --------- beginning of crash
>   07-12 18:30:15.773 2689-2689/com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                             Process: com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound, PID: 2689
>                                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound/com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                 at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.(FirebaseArray.java:43)
>                                                                                                 at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.(FirebaseListAdapter.java:93)
>                                                                                                 at com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound.MainActivity$1.(MainActivity.java:0)
>                                                                                                 at com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
>   07-12 18:30:15.773 2689-2689/com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound/com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.(FirebaseArray.java:43)
>                                                                                                    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.(FirebaseListAdapter.java:93)
>                                                                                                    at com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound.MainActivity$1.(MainActivity.java:0)
>                                                                                                    at com.newworldgrip.lostandfound.lostandfound.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
>   any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exception do you get? Please edit your question to include the complete stack trace (which you can get from logcat).

Comment: Frank van Puffelen, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, Android is asynchronous which means it doesn't wait on auth state listener and jumps right into database analyzing.

All I had to do is to put the database and list adapter inside the listener.

Answer (score 0):

A quick first guess is that your subviews are not being found in `populateView`, because you're searching them globally:

```
((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.requestName)).setText(model.getRequestName());
```

The `v.` in there is new and makes sure you're searching for a `TextView` inside the view of this specific item, instead of a global one.